# Access SQL files inside Node project

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, file

Is there a way to access SQL files created during development of a Node project?

I have a file `database_initialization.sql` holding a number of commands. Its purpose is to create the basic structure of the database. I want it to start when the database name within a MySQL database could not be found. Currently, the content of this SQL file is copied into the updating TypeScript file as a `const sql: string = 'CREATE DATABASE myDatabase; USE myDatabase; CREATE TABLE ...';`. I would like to have the variable `sql` filled by the SQL file rather than having a copy of its content in another file.

The file `database_initialization.sql` is in the same directory as the TypeScript file, during development. My current attempt does not work:

`const sql: string = readFileSync('database_initialization.sql').toString();`

**EDIT 1:**

The error given when trying to `readFileSync`:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'database_initialization.sql'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at Function.initializeDatabase (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/src/Data/Update/UpdateQuery.ts:7:29)
    at Handshake.ApiServer.db.connect (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/src/ApiServer.ts:45:25)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:491:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
```

Comment: what error do you get on your `readFileSync`?  Guessing it doesn't know the directory to find that file?

Comment: @Joe Added error in **EDIT 1**.

Comment: Yeah, you just need to figure out the path OR do something like `const sql: string = readFileSync(__dirname + 'database_initialization.sql').toString();`

Comment: @Joe That did it. The `__dirname` + `/` + `database_initialization.sql`. Thanks a lot!